# c# Acces to the path \downloads is denied

Tags: c#, file

I am currently working on a project where you can download files from an ftp server.

When I try to download the file, i get an error says that access to the path 'C\Users\Administrator\Downloads' is denied. [image of the error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jnp5c.png)

is there any way that i can solve this?

```
        try
        {
            string ResponseDescription = "";
            string downloads;
            SHGetKnownFolderPath(KnownFolder.Downloads, 0, IntPtr.Zero, out downloads);

            string inputfilepath = downloads;
            string UserName = "UserName";
            string Password = "Password";
            string folderName = "folderName";
            string targetFile = "targetfilename"
            string Server = "ftp://ip/" + folderName +"/" + targetfile;

            FtpWebRequest req = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(Server);
            req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);
            req.UseBinary = true;
            req.Proxy = null;

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(downloads, FileMode.Create);
            int ReadCount = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            while (ReadCount > 0)
            {
                fs.Write(buffer, 0, ReadCount);
                ReadCount = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
            ResponseDescription = response.StatusDescription;
            fs.Close();
            stream.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception x)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant to append a filename to that path?

Comment: Your image shows the path as `C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads` but your post refers to `C\Users\Alfe\Downloads`. You should first ensure the path is correct, then if it is you should check the user you are running your process under has permissions to the download folder.

Comment: @quaabaam I tested the program on two different computers. That's why the path is different. I ensure the path is correct, and I also ensure the user has permission to the download folder. Do you have any other ideas that can solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is incorrectly trying to open the target file. First, the variable `downloads` is initialized from the known folder "downloads", which would contain the path to the **folder** of downloads.

Then, you just use that variable right away to open the file for writing. But you can't write to a folder, you write to a **file**! The access denied you get is because of that fact, not because of permissions (a rather obscure exception message). You need to create the `FileStream` using the **file** path you want to open.

In short, you need to change this line:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(downloads, FileMode.Create);
```

Into something like this:

```
string downloadFilePath = Path.Combine(downloads, "file.txt");  // Replace "file.txt" with the actual file name
FileStream fs = new FileStream(downloadFilePath, FileMode.Create);
```

BTW, and unrelated to the question itself, there are quite a few disposable objects being used there. Make sure to use `using` in all instances.